# Transform SQL Log using python

Tags: python, logging

I have a task to transform SQL Statement captured in the log by listing down respective table. Below is the sample of log data

| Username | Date | Query |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bob | 01/10/23 | select * from table1, table2 where table1.id = table2.table1id |
| john | 15/10/23 | select * from dbo.table3 |

Outcome shall be

| Username | Date | Tables |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bob | 01/10/23 | table1 |
| bob | 01/10/23 | table2 |
| john | 15/10/23 | table3 |

I tried to use SPLIT_STRING in SQL. However data are moved to cloud and I need to use Python.